# How do I create a batch file to enter data in a text file

Tags: batch-file

Ive done some research on this but with minimal luck. What I have is a batch file that installs several programs for me. One of the programs requires the creation of an .INI file. basically it adds a username and password to the program

```
@echo off

echo Enter a Username:

echo Enter a Password:

set /p boompanes=

pause

echo %boompanes%> Visual.ini
```

This creates the ini file with the one line of code but I need it in a certain spot on the file. see below

```
echo off
echo. >"C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Visual.ini
echo enter a Username:
echo enter a Password:
pause
```

The outcome of the file needs to be identical to the following:

```
[Visual Mfg]
Userid= *username*
Password= *password*
Database=VMFG
```

With just the *username* and *password* being modified.

With this code it creates the .ini file but its empty as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i understand that you what the output you wrote there, 
to do this you must know somethings:

first line you use >file.ini
second and n lines you will need to add value to file.ini using >> not only >
you will need to set another variable for the password then print everything,

```
@echo off

echo Enter a Username:

set /p user=

echo Enter a Password:

set /p pass=

pause

echo [Visual Mfg]> Visual.ini
echo Userid=*%user%*>> Visual.ini
echo password=*%pass%*>> Visual.ini
echo Database=VMFG>> Visual.ini
```

i hope that that what you really need.

Comment: The code looks less cluttered when enclosing the 4 echo commands in parentheses and applying only one redirection to the whole `(code block) >Visual.ini`.

Comment: Ok so it does work. Thanks. So how do I make it save in a specific location? I want it to save the ini in C:Infor\Visual\"Visual MFG"\Visual.ini

Comment: @rickityrickitywrecked you can use echo xxx >"C:Infor\Visual\"Visual MFG"\Visual.ini"